# N-body simulation on Fortran leap frog algorithm

Tags: fortran

I am using a simple 'leapfrog algorithm I am aiming to simulate the orbits of the earth a Jupiter around the sun. I am unable to get them to orbit despite being fairly sure the maths is correct. It appears that gravity is acting too weekly and the planet merely floats away from the sun, interestingly if I adjust the Newtonian acceleration due to gravity term by multiplying it by rad2 I find that the system does indeed produce fairly stable orbits but at much much too large radii.

```
program physim
  Implicit none
  integer :: i,j,n,day ! Integer variables
  doubleprecision :: G , r(1:3,1:10) , a(1:3, 1:10) , v(1:3, 1:10) , m(1:3), dt, Au, dr(1:3), 
rad2(1:3), t, tcount, tend, tout

! constants
day = 86400
tout = 10*day
tend = 20*day

Au = 15e11
n = 3
G = 6.67e-11
!n = 2
dt = 100
!sun
r(1,1) = 0.
r(2,1) = 0.
r(3,1) = 0.
v(1,1) = 0.
v(2,1) = 0.
v(3,1) = 0.
m(1) = 1.9898e30
!earth
r(1,2) = Au
r(2,2) = 0.
r(3,2) = 0.
v(1,2) = 0.
v(2,2) = 30000
v(3,2) = 0.
m(2) = 6e24
!jupiter
r(1,3) = 5.2*Au
r(2,3) = 0.
r(3,3) = 0.
v(1,3) = 0.
v(2,3) = 13070
v(3,3) = 0.
m(3) = 2e27


do
a = 0
tcount = 0
do i = 1, n
    do j = 1, n
        !calculating acceleration
    if (i==j)cycle
    dr(1:3) = r(1:3, j) - r(1:3, i)

    rad2 = dr(1)**2 + dr(2)**2 + dr(3)**2
    a(1:3, i) = a(1:3, i) + G*m(j)*dr(1:3)/(rad2*sqrt(rad2))


    end do
end do

do i = 1, n
    r(1:3 ,i) = r(1:3, i) + v(1:3, i)*dt
    v(1:3, i) = v(1:3, i) + a(1:3, i)*dt

end do
t = t + dt
tcount = t + dt
if(tcount>tout) then
!write(6,*) a(1,2)
!write(6,*) rad2


write(6,*) a(1,1) , a(2,1), a(3, 2)


end if

end do
end program
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is [debug your program](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). If that doesn't show you the problem, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60696371/edit) to show us the part of your code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You will have to show us the output of your program and point out where those results are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most fundamental problem was that 1 A.U. = 1.5e11 m, not 15e11. Then you were doing stuff like resetting `tcount` every trip through the loop. Set it before the start of the main loop and then only reset when you print out a line of output. It should be updated as `tcount=tcount+dt` and then you probably want to print out `r(1,2) , r(2,2), r(1,3) , r(2,3)` so you can plot the positions of jupiter and earth. Also you should maybe go for more time so you can see a few full orbits of earth, and finally put a test at the bottom of the loop so it will exit when `t>tend`. Making these changes I got output that looked like this:
[image: fig 1]